# Postgresql: Find the average in millions, extract the year from (yyyy-mm-dd) date column, and use where

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM date) as year from table,

AVG(employment_1000s)/1000 as avg_employment_millions FROM table

WHERE table.state = 'California'

AND table.industry = 'Gov'

AND year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2006;
```

ERROR: syntax error at or near "/" LINE 2: AVG(employment_1000s)/1000 as avg_employment_millions FROM b... ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 72

How to fix the error and create a valid code?

Comment: So first of all welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest taking the [tour] if you are new. Thank you for providing the code but can you please also provide the input and expected output? Also the tracelog/error message would be very useful for helping you. So please help us, help you. As is, if I tried to run your code to find the error and fix it I'd get nothing as I do not have any of your data.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post and add that in as part of the question?

Comment: I think I might. Can you provide the current column name in the table and the related datatypes? Also A bit of confusion the error states `AVG(employment_1000s)/1000 ` is the error but your provided code reads `AVG(column_in_1000s)/1000`

Comment: employment_1000s

Answer (score 1):

You have two `from` clauses and that's confusing the parser.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM date) as year from table,
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^

AVG(employment_1000s)/1000 as avg_employment_millions FROM table
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
WHERE table.state = 'California'

AND table.industry = 'Gov'

AND year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2006;
```

Remove the first one.

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(year FROM date) as year,
  AVG(employment_1000s)/1000 as avg_employment_millions
FROM "table"
WHERE state = 'California'
  AND industry = 'Gov'
  AND year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2006;
```

---

However, that won't work. You're using an aggregate function, `avg`, without aggregating with a [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp). Second, you can't use a derived column, `year`, in a where clause.

You have to group by year (I assume), and repeat the extraction.

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(year FROM date) as year,
  AVG(employment_1000s)/1000 as avg_employment_millions
FROM states
WHERE state = 'California'
  AND industry = 'Gov'
  AND extract(year from date) between 2005 and 2006
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM date)
```

Or do the grouping in a [CTE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cte/) and then select from that.

```
with california_gov_years as (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(year FROM date) as year,
    AVG(employment_1000s)/1000 as avg_employment_millions
  FROM states
  WHERE state = 'California'
    AND industry = 'Gov'
  group by year
)
select *
from california_gov_years
where year between 2005 and 2006
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/b17kHWe5).

---

Note, `year` and `date` are [SQL keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Avoid using them as column names, they can cause confusion. They're also not descriptive of what the date is. Consider, for example, `created_on` instead.

Comment: Unlikely this query is going to work, "year" is constructed in the SELECT and does not exist as column that can be used in the where condition. (unfortunately, other databases do allow this). You have to use EXTRACT() or something like: date between '2005-01-01' and '2006-12-31'